# Images don't show up in ListView

Tags: android

i'm trying to make a sort of image diary where one can create post with images. First i had the problem that every post showed the same image, but tried to fix it with File.createTempFile. But now nothing is showing and i get a lot of null pointer exceptions.

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /**
     *Gets the images taken with the camera, depended on how many pictures were taken, they are saved in images.
     **/
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == this.getActivity().RESULT_OK && counter <= 2) {
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");


        switch (counter) {
            case 0:
                im1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                Log.d(this.getActivity().getPackageName(), bmp != null ? "bmp is not null!" : "bmp is null!");
                images.add(saveToInternalStorage(bmp));



                counter++;
                break;
            case 1:
                im2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im2.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                //pathList.add(1,saveToInternalStorage(bmp));
                images.add(saveToInternalStorage(bmp));

                counter++;

                break;
            case 2:
                im3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                im3.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                images.add(saveToInternalStorage(bmp));

                counter++;
                break;
        }
```

...

```
     private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath = null;
    try {
        mypath = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", directory);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

...Is in my Adapter

```
    private Bitmap loadImageFromStorage(String path) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    File f= null;

    try {
        f =  new File(path);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

Updated my code above, but no i get this exception. I think maybe the error is with the File.createTempFile when a image is saved and the load function to get the image again, can it be something i missed there?

fixed the exception but i still don't get the images

Comment: All I can see is, you need to try debugging. Also your log says "ContentItem.getImageNames()' on a null object reference" check it first.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **loadImageFromStorage(String path, int i) method**
line

```
String name = p.getImageNames().get(i);
```

is giving you error make sure you are setting arraylist on your instance variable p and, then try to get that list.